# Text side-by-side latex beamer

Tags: beamer, itemize, minipage

```
\begin{frame}{Workload Categorization}
Benchmark suites:\hspace{4cm}64bit architectures:
\begin{itemize}
    \item 22 SPECcpu2006\hspace{3.5cm}  Intel SandyBridge
    \item 11 SPLASH2x\hspace{4.1cm} AMD Opteron
    \item 9 PARSEC 3.0\hspace{4.1cm} ARM Juno
    \item 6 NAS 
\end{itemize}
Categorize benchmarks\footcite{Sanchez et al ISCA'11}:
\begin{itemize}
    \item Insensitive (N)
    \item Cache-Friendly (F)
    \item Cache-Fitting (T)
    \item Thrashing/Streaming (S)
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
```

How do I have a minipage to have 64bit architectures on the right side with a itemize instead of hspace?
and also the citation: how do I ensure numbers continue instead of a new number?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an alternative solution using minipages.

```
\documentclass[demo]{beamer}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Workload Categorization}
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\linewidth}
Benchmark suites:
\begin{itemize}
    \item 22 SPECcpu2006
    \item 11 SPLASH2x
    \item 9 PARSEC 3.0
    \item 6 NAS 
\end{itemize}   
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\linewidth}
64bit architectures:
\setlength{\leftmargini}{0pt}
\setbeamertemplate{itemize items}{}
\begin{itemize}
    \item Intel SandyBridge
    \item AMD Opteron
    \item ARM Juno
\end{itemize}
\end{minipage}\par
\vspace{2em}
Categorize benchmarks\footcite{Sanchez et al ISCA'11}:
\begin{itemize}
    \item Insensitive (N)
    \item Cache-Friendly (F)
    \item Cache-Fitting (T)
    \item Thrashing/Streaming (S)
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a bit hacked, but does work.
We use two columns with a List in each one, so that the items are next to each other. Then we remove the bullets and indentation from the second list.
Perhaps you want to fiddle with the width to get the distance between the two lists to your liking:

```
\documentclass[demo]{beamer}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setitemize{label=\usebeamerfont*{itemize item}%
    \usebeamercolor[fg]{itemize item}
    \usebeamertemplate{itemize item}}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{explanation}
\begin{columns}
    \begin{column}[t]{0.33\textwidth}
        Benchmark suites:
        \begin{itemize}
            \item 22 SPECcpu2006
            \item 11 SPLASH2x
            \item 9 PARSEC 3.0
            \item 6 NAS 
        \end{itemize}
    \end{column}
    \begin{column}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
        64bit architectures:
        \begin{itemize} [label={},leftmargin=0cm]
            \item Intel SandyBridge
            \item AMD Opteron
            \item ARM Juno
        \end{itemize}
    \end{column}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably want something like that using columns:

```
\documentclass[demo]{beamer}
\begin{document}
  \begin{frame}
\frametitle{explanation}
\begin{columns}
\begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
    Benchmark suites:\hspace{4cm}64bit architectures:
    \begin{itemize}
        \item 22 SPECcpu2006\hspace{3.5cm}  Intel SandyBridge
        \item 11 SPLASH2x\hspace{4.1cm} AMD Opteron
        \item 9 PARSEC 3.0\hspace{4.1cm} ARM Juno
        \item 6 NAS 
    \end{itemize}
\end{column}
\begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}  %%<--- here
    Categorize benchmarks\footcite{Sanchez et al ISCA'11}:
    \begin{itemize}
        \item Insensitive (N)
        \item Cache-Friendly (F)
        \item Cache-Fitting (T)
        \item Thrashing/Streaming (S)
    \end{itemize}
\end{column}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

This should keep citations the way you want them.
If you want to keep the columns vertically aligned, just add `[t]` after `\begin{column}`. You might add an empty line after "Categorize benchmarks" so that the lists are aligned also.

Comment: No, this is mixing both 64bit architectures and benchmark suites under the same heading one below the other.

I would like to have a different itemize for each of them. basically have a minipage and use the left column for benchmark and categorization and the right half for architectures

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry. I think my next answer is nearer to what you want.