# footcite side-by-side other instead of top-to-below.

Tags: beamer, bibtex, citing

Here is the MWE I'm using.. 
I want the footcite to be side-by-side instead of top-to-bottom  because it is taking too much space otherwise.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{beamer}
%\usetheme{Boadilla}%CambridgeUS}
\usetheme{CambridgeUS}
\usepackage[british,UKenglish,USenglish,english,american]{babel}
\hypersetup{pdfstartview={Fit}}

\setbeamercovered{dynamic}

\useinnertheme{default}
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}
\usefonttheme{serif}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{appendixnumberbeamer}
\usepackage{caption}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{textpos}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{pgf}

\let\oldfootnotesize\footnotesize
\renewcommand*{\footnotesize}{\oldfootnotesize\tiny}
\newcommand{\tick}{\ding{52}}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark,fit}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\newcommand\blfootnote[1]{%
  \begingroup
  \renewcommand\thefootnote{}\footnote{#1}%
  \addtocounter{footnote}{-1}%
  \endgroup
}
\setbeamertemplate{itemize items}[default]
\setbeamertemplate{enumerate items}[default]

\usepackage{siunitx} % use this package module for SI units
\sisetup{per-mode=symbol}
\sisetup{binary-units=true}
\DeclareBinaryPrefix\Kilo{K}{10}
\providecommand{\e}[1]{\ensuremath{\times 10^{#1}}}
\newcommand{\sn}[2]{\ensuremath{{#1}\times 10^{#2}}}
\DeclareSIUnit\year{yr}


\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Architecture Categorisation}

\begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}
    Power meters:
    \begin{itemize}
        \item baz~\footcite{firstauthor conf'11}
        \item foo~\footcite{fistauthorfor conf11}

        \item bar~\footcite{firstauthor conf11}
    \end{itemize}
\end{minipage}\par
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to help.. :-(

Comment: Unfortunately even that does not help for `footcite` or `footnote`.. even if it made it `multicol`. that'll save me some space.

`multicol` with `top-to-bottom` is the best course of action though

Comment: Just an update: that link works for non minipage. but still with minipage is the issue.

Comment: I split the frame into a quadrant. this is one part of it. something like this: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/307438/text-side-by-side-latex-beamer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this? It relies on [`parnotes`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/parnotes?lang=en).

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{parnotes}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Architecture Categorisation}
\begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}
    Power meters:
    \begin{itemize}
        \item baz~\parnote{firstauthor conf'11}
        \item foo~\parnote{fistauthorfor conf11}
        \item bar~\parnote{firstauthor conf11}
    \end{itemize}
\end{minipage}\par
%\vfill % <-- compare difference
\parnotes
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Of course, lots of people will probably tell you to avoid footnotes in presentations. But a judicious breaking of nearly any typographic rule can be appropriate in the right circumstances.

Comment: How else would you add presentations in presentations?

Comment: The operative assumption is that you shouldn't need to: (1) because the slides are not a proxy for the whole presentation, but should contain only minimal information in each slide to *complement* the talk rather than *supplement* it; (2) because you can co-create a 'handout' that contains more information than the slides should; and (3) it can overwhelm the viewer and distract her from the talk. Like I said, however, I can envisage times when a footnote or two may be appropriate. But footnote**s** on every slide?  Probably too much....

Comment: I kind of see your point, but from what I see academic presentations do have a lot of references.. maybe I am wrong. 
Do you think having it at the end of the presentation after the back-up slides is a good idea?

Eitherway, the solution you gave works.

Comment: Absolutely: academic presentations often have lots of references. But, then again, academics-as-a-class usually have no interest in the finer points of typography or what makes for a good presentation. (Exceptions abound, of course, but they are exceptions, not the rule.) One idea might be to have it on a handout that people can grab if they want. They may appreciate that more than needing to scrawl down citations while simultaneously trying to follow the points **you** are making. A quick comment near the start of the talk that a more detailed handout is available should suffice.

Comment: I agree with you on the point that, cluttering the page isn't in the best interest of the listener. 
But again, typography is a picky deal, and I would not say that it is not something `acadamic`. 

Just an example of what I am speaking is available here: http://wpage.unina.it/agodemar/DSV-DQV/DSV-DQV_Quaderno_1.pdf (taken from http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/74615/26232)

I think that professor put LOTS of time and effort to make this presentation, which I appreciate and makes me more eager to learn!)

Comment: It is a remarkable piece of work (I gave it a +1, too, some time ago) -- but not a set of slides for a presentation so much as something to be read, which is where footnotes are appropriate. It was certainly not created with `beamer` or any similar class (e.g., `powerdot`).  And I agree that typography is important, even in an academic paper: my point is only that most academics don't know (or care to know) anything about it: they write in MS Word, they create PowerPoint slides, and they settle for the defaults of those programs ... and they may well put footnotes where they don't help much.